# Azure EventHub Premium Throughput Limit

Tags: azure, limit, azure-eventhub, quota

What are the throughput limits of Azure Event Hub we have to calculate when using Event Hub Premium?

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quotas#basic-vs-standard-vs-premium-vs-dedicated-tiers) says there are no limits per PU when using the Premium tier but i don't understand what that means.

If there are no limits why should i ever then use more than 1 PU ?

We currently calculate with 15 MB / second ingress and activating capture which results in roughly €2000.

When i compare this to premium where capture and ingress is included, 1 PU only costs ~ € 900. So this would save us a lot of money but i'm just now sure if 1 PU can handle 15 MB / second ingress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [Scaling with Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-scalability#processing-units), which describes some of the considerations in more detail.

With respect to processing units, the docs say:

> How much you can ingest and stream with a processing unit depends on various factors such as your producers, consumers, the rate at which you're ingesting and processing, and much more. One processing unit can approximately offer core capacity of ~5-10 MB/s ingress and 10-20 MB/s egress, given that we have sufficient partitions so that storage is not a throttling factor.

Based on that, it seems as though you'll need at least 2 PUs to handle your 15mbps ingress rate.